# How can I disallow files to be uploaded in a certain directory?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have a FTP user, their default directory is `/home/user/`. I am in need of a setting that will remove the ability for files, and directories in that directory. However, they can freely create new files and folders in any folders that already exist in `/home/user/`.

How can this be done?

Comment: To clarify: you only want to remove access to create and modify in the root folder `/home/user`, but allow access to everything in sub-folders below that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove write permission on `/home/user/` the user won't be able to create, delete or rename files and directories in `/home/user/`. You should retain write permission on the subdirectories which you want the user to be able to modify.